# how to merge two sqlite3 databases with same schema having primary key with auto increment

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I want to merge two or more `sqlite databases` with `same schema` in which one of the columns in each databases has primary key with autoincrement.

For ex : 
I have two databases : 
`student1.db`

`idx`  `name` `age`

1. abc   15
2. def   16
3. ghi   15
4. jkl   16

another DB : `student2.db`

`idx`   `name`   `age`

1. mno     15
2. pqr     16
3. stu     16
4. vwx     15

I have added column `idx` as `primary key` with `auto increment`.

Now I want to merge `student2.db` with `student1.db` without creating `temp db`. 
some what after merging it `student1.db` should look like below.

**`student1.db after merge`**:

`idx`   `name`   `age

1. abc     15
2. def     16
3. ghi     15
4. jkl     16
5. mno     15
6. pqr     16
7. stu     16
8. vwx     15

I know we can use attach. But that will not merge if one of the columns is `primary key` with auto increment. After merge I want the idx column to append with the `existing idx` column in incremental fashion.

Below is the `.schema for student1 and student2 db`.

**`sqlite3 student1.db`**

**sqlite> .schema**

```
CREATE TABLE student (

 'idx' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,

 'name' CHAR(32) NOT NULL,

 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL default 0,

  UNIQUE (name)

  );


 sqlite> select * from student;

  1|abc|15

  2|def|16

  3|ghi|15

  4|jkl|16

  sqlite>

  sqlite3 student2.db

  SQLite version 3.6.20

  Enter ".help" for instructions

  Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

  sqlite> .schema

  CREATE TABLE student (

  'idx' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,

  'name' CHAR(32) NOT NULL,

  'age' INTEGER NOT NULL default 0,

   UNIQUE (name)

  );

  sqlite> select * from student;

  1|mno|15

  2|pqr|16

  3|stu|15

  4|vwx|16

  sqlite>



 This is what I used to merge two database. 

 attach './student2.db' as toMerge;

 BEGIN;

  insert or ignore into student

  select * from toMerge.student;

  COMMIT;

  detach database toMerge;
```

Please let me know **how I can merge two databases with primary key**
Your help in this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite creates new IDs when the inserted value for a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is NULL.

So you have to copy all columns *except* the ID:

```
INSERT INTO student(name, age)
SELECT name, age
FROM toMerge.student;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed the steps suggested by you and it worked for me in merging the two databases.